# MySQL, compare date is less then another when in format DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a due date for tasks, stored in the database as '10-nov-2011'.

Is there someone I can do a query to select all tasks that due date is less then now?

A straight out due < today doesn't work.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to change the format of your due date column to a proper mySQL `DATETIME`. Doing this with the format you show is very complicated and very resource heavy (as mySQL can't use any indexes and quick comparisons)

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: varchar, there are about 100 rows, there will never be more than a few hundred rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the column to type [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html). Then your query will work.

If you can't change the column type, use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to parse the string into a date.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(due, '%d-%b-%Y') < NOW()
```

Comment: If I do that it wipes out all my existing date data.. prob can't conver it?

Comment: @Brettski: You'll have to write a migration script. You can use `STR_TO_DATE` to help you migrate the data.

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates are in the above format then you could convert the characters to dates and your comparison will work using just the less than or greater than comparisons.

To convert your string to date just try this

```
select str_to_date('10-nov-2011','%d-%b-%Y');
```

Given your example and assuming your column is called due_date and your table is called tasks, your query would be something like

```
select * 
from tasks 
where str_to_date(due_date,'%d-%b-%Y') < CURDATE();
```

Comment: Thank you, you both got it for me :)